# how find the angles of a triangle with values that the user enters and how to draw it

Tags: python

im a beginner to python and I have to write a program that Asks the user for 3 numbers(sides of a triangle), Determines whether or not the numbers form valid sides of a triangle, If they don’t, say it doesn’t and end the program. If they do, determine the ANGLES of this triangle and Draw the triangle on the screen using turtle. I don't really know what im doing and so far I was able to get the user to enter the values and a get the program to determine if it is a triangle or not, but when I try to determine the angles, I get 2 different errors. the first one values error: math domain error and the other one is that I have to convert a string to real numbers. This is the code that I have so far:

```
from turtle import*
from math import*
import math

a = int(input("enter the value for a: "))
b = int(input("enter the value for b: "))
c = int(input("enter the value for c: "))


 if a^2 + b^2 == c^2:
    print("its a triangle")
else:
    print("its not a triangle")


if (math.acos(a)):
    print(degrees(acos(cos(radians(a)))))
elif (math.acos(b)):
    print(degrees(acos(cos(radians(b)))))
elif(math.acos(c)):
    print(degrees(acos(cos(radians(c)))))


a = degrees(int(acos('a^2 - b^2 - c^2 / -2(b)(c)')))
b = degrees(int(acos('b^2 - c^2 - a^2 / -2(a)(c)')))
c = degrees(int(acos('c^2 - a^2 - b^2 / -2(a)(b)')))
```

Comment: 1) the indentation's off; 2) in Python, `^` is the XOR bit wise operator, it doesn't raise stuff to powers; 3) why... are you trying to compute an arccosine of strings??

Comment: im trying to get inverse cosine to find the angles but im really lost and how does someone raise something to a power

Comment: You should learn a bit of Python first (it's really not that hard, there's a great tutorial at http://python.org), you won't get much progress otherwise.

Comment: I understand some things but this is part of a project and im just not sure why I keep getting errors but thank you for the advice

Comment: ad 2) of @ForceBru: even if you correctly exponentiate (**), you'd be testing the triangle for being right. Only a tiny portion of triangles is right. 4) currently, you impose the order on the sides (hypotenuse comes last). How is the user supposed to know that?

Comment: @dedObed, exactly: if `a**2 + b**2 != c**2`, it doesn't mean that no such triangle exists. There are other (correct) ways to determine that.

Comment: Note also that, unlike what you write in maths,  you have to explicitly use the multiplication operator `*` between variables. Also, `acos()` returns an angle between 0 and pi, and `int(acos(...))` will give you the integer part of this value, which is not what you want.

Comment: so then there are other ways to determine the angles using the law of cosine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through a bit at a time: although wildcard imports are generally frowned upon, it is more usual syntax to use

```
from turtle import *
from math import *
import math
```

You said you wanted to input real numbers; in Python, such numbers are of the class `float`, so this code should read

```
a = float(input("enter the value for a: "))
b = float(input("enter the value for b: "))
c = float(input("enter the value for c: "))
```

This next section seems a little odd. Firstly, note that in Python `a^2` is bitwise XOR, which is not what you want; exponentiation would be performed with `a**2`. More crucially, this is mathematically flawed. `a**2 + b**2 == c**2` is only true when the triangle is right-angled with `c` being the hypotenuse (this is Pythagoras' theorem). Instead, a triangle is only valid when `a`, `b`, and `c` satisfy the triangle inequalities, namely `a + b >= c`, `b + c >= a`, and `c + a >= b`. Thus this section should be (with punctuation corrections):

```
if (a + b >= c) and (b + c >= a) and (c + a >= b):
    print("it's a triangle")
else:
    print("it's not a triangle")
```

The next section seems a little odd, and I have no idea what it's trying to do. Scrap it.

The following section has a few issues:

- `int(acos(...))` rounds `acos` down to an integer, which, as you're working in radians at that point, will cause you to lose a vast amount of precision.
- `(a)(b)` is not valid syntax for multiplication in Python; instead one must use `a*b`.
- again, `^` is not exponentiation; `**` should be used instead.
- For some reason you've put `a^2 - b^2 - c^2 / -2(b)(c)` in quotes, which turns it into a string; when you do this, it is stored as text and not evaluated.
- You've unnecessarily negated both the numerator and the denominator; this can be removed to make the formula more standard.
- You're overwriting the length measurements by setting `a =`; it is standard mathematical notaion to have capital `A`, `B`, and `C` be angles.

This section of code should be:

```
A = degrees(acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)))
B = degrees(acos((c**2 + a**2 - b**2)/(2*c*a)))
C = degrees(acos((a**2 + b**2 - c**2)/(2*a*b)))
```

Additionally, you may not want to evaluate the angles if it's an invalid triangle. To implement this, simply move the last section to within the `if` statement. Thus the final code is:

```
from turtle import *
from math import *
import math

a = float(input("enter the value for a: "))
b = float(input("enter the value for b: "))
c = float(input("enter the value for c: "))

if (a + b >= c) and (b + c >= a) and (c + a >= b):
    print("it's a triangle")

    A = degrees(acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)))
    B = degrees(acos((c**2 + a**2 - b**2)/(2*c*a)))
    C = degrees(acos((a**2 + b**2 - c**2)/(2*a*b)))
else:
    print("it's not a triangle")
```

Thus the angles can be computed from the sides.

You also wanted to know how to use `turtle` to draw the triangle; I recommend that, as this appears to be a homework task or similar, that you actually learn how to use `turtle`. [Here is a simple tutorial.](https://github.com/asweigart/simple-turtle-tutorial-for-python/blob/master/simple_turtle_tutorial.md)